# Analysis of a motor/generator set for the replacement of diesel engines

Tags: motor, dc-motor, generator

I would like to supply a 12 VDC, 3500 RPM permanent-magnet motor with a 24 V battery using a 12 V voltage regulator.

The motor will be coupled to a 220 V, 1.2 kW, 50 Hz, 1450 RPM generator. The power produced by the generator will be used to recharge the battery.

I want to simulate all this in software and see how much time it will take for this system to stop and how efficient it will be.

[image]

Apart from MATLAB, in which other electrical software can I model and simulate a motor/generator set and analyze its behavior?

Comment: Depends on what you want to analyse about its behaviour. What's wrong with using MATLAB? I'd suggest PLECs or you could do simple analysis by hand. The real question is what are you looking for?

Comment: I will like to supply a 12VDC, 3500 rpm permanent magnet motor with a 24V battery, will use a 12V voltage regulator. Couple the motor with a generator, 220V, 1.2kW, 50 Hz, 1450 rpm. Use the voltage produced by the generator to recharge the battery. For all this, i will like to run it in a software and see how much time will it take this system to stop and how efficient will it be?

Comment: I don't want to use MATLAB (Simulink) because i am failing to come up with this connection, i can't find the right motor and generator to use

Comment: What's wrong with doing it by hand? You've only got one state your interested in, so it's just power flows with effiecny drops along the way: it goes out of battery then, drop in regulator, drop in controller (if applicable), drop in motor, drop in generator, drop in controller (if applicable), drop in battery charger. You can add up all the drops and you're done.

Comment: Pardon me please, do you mean doing hand calculations or setting up the whole system and take readings from a working system.

Answer (score 0):

How about [SPICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE)?

> As SPICE generally solves non-linear differential algebraic equations, it may be applied to simulating beyond the electrical realm.  ... it will equally well describe the electro-mechanical model of the motor.

(From the linked Wikipedia article.)